# asp.net mvc3 razor and jquery submit

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, forms, razor

I have post form with submit button before submit i need to call c# code behind get hash and then change value of hidden input.

Code behind is calling but problem is that while i get result from c# code form is submiting how i can first get result and then submit form?

Jquery:

```
$('#pay_form').submit(function(){
       GetHash();
    });


 function GetHash()
    {
        var amount = $('#txtInAmount').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Transactions/GetOrderCodeHah',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { Amount: amount },
            success: function (result){
                $('#txtOrderCode').val('231321321321321321');
                $('#txtCheck').val(result.hash);
            },
            error: function(){
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Why on earth are you doing that? Why not do it all after submitting?

Comment: And how i can do that? can you provide some examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `return false;` from the `submit()` handler, then explicitly `submit()` the form in the AJAX callback.

Comment: and how i can submit in ajax callback?

Comment: `$('#pay_form')[0].submit()`.  The `[0]` gets the native DOM element, to avoid firing your submit handler again.